# Android fragment based open source project

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-listfragment

I am looking for an open source project using fragment activities

I have seen plenty of examples for fragments but haven't seen real world implementations, or any implementations of fragment activities that have any utility (outside of explicitly being an example)

Would like link to any repository or a known apps that use fragments (even your own)

Comment: This might help: http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/checkout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it makes sense to study [Google I/O application](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/checkout). Because it's from Google and it's more or less simple and yet covers many things.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of apps which use fragment. 
Indeed, developer which provide android app for tabs and smartphone without using fragments don't really understand Android.

I have a really small project on Github which use Fragment:
https://github.com/StephaneC/SouthPark-Soundbox
I think that you can find much better (dev of this  app has been stopped) but it could be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

It's older, and was done while I was doing my senior year at college, but you can take a look at my simplistic android app which uses 2 fragments to support phone and tablet layouts.

[www.github.com/zerkz](http://www.github.com/zerkz)

Disclaimer: There are some bad practices in my code. For example, all DB calls are performed on the UI thread because they are extremely fast enough that it doesn't matter. The way I access fragments by not be the norm either. I was taking 18 credits around this time so I didn't have the time to polish it up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the top open-source apps that you can check out. It has also been adopted to large screen devices such as tablets too.

> [Astrid](https://github.com/todoroo/astrid)